# Most non-confrontational delimiter for my text files?

Tags: text-files

I am saving all my notes in a log file. Each line is a note, suffixed by tags, and prefixed by a date and time marker, which currently looks like this: `[12.20.09:22.22]` (`[date:time]`.

I am planning to have this a long-living format. Notes will be logged willy-nilly with this format 20-30 times a day for years to come. I foresee numerous kinds of parsing for analytics, filtering, searching ...

I am worried about the `[ ]`s though. Could they possibly trip some parsing code (someone else's if not mine)? What would be the most non-confrontational marker?

Answer (score 5):

If you end up going with your own format, can I recommend [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format) for your date and time format.

In summary, the basic format is:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

You can extend this with timezone and microsecond info if you wish. Timezone is recommended or assume UTC.

With the date/time in this format there's no confusion over which is the month and the day. And it has the bonus of sorting using a basic string sort.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using either XML or JSON as the format for the file.

In particular your date/time marker is ambiguous. Is it mm/dd/yy or dd/mm/yy? Or even yy/mm/dd? And in what timezone is the date and time?

Both XML and JSON define a way to have dates that are culture and timezone independent, and (best of all) there's masses of tooling available for both formats.

XML datetime format is defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats): for example, 2000-01-12T12:13:14Z.

JSON datetime format is defined as [the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970](http://www.nikhilk.net/Entry.aspx?id=145), so it's a bit uglier: { currentDate: "@1163531522089@" }

Comment: Both JSON and XML are very unpractical to write manually, and are not well suited for an automated log since you need to unserialize and serialize again to add an entry. Moreover, JSON doesn't define a date format, the link is just the solution that someone came up with but it's not standard. The XML dates are just ISO 8601, a format that can be used anywhere, not just in XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything to last in a long-lived format, then the metadata needs to be as explicit as possible.  If it's intended to be long-lived, then many others will need to read it, as easily as possible.

I agree with Jeremy McGee: XML is an excellent choice.  Even if no other data lives, then having it be in the format:

```
<note>
   <datetime>
      <year>
         2009
      </year>
      <month>
         12
      </month>
  . . .
   </datetime>
   <message>
      Foo bar baz quox
   </message>
<note>
```

cannot be misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah that's explicit, but it's also painfully verbose. I would think on average that you would have more bytes devoted to XML tags than usable data.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your data.  However, if you escape them with a special character of some sort, (i.e. `\]`) and code accordingly to look at the previous character when finding a "[" or "]", you should have no problem.

Also, if you're open to a new format, I'm a fan of JSON as it's light weight and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using '[]' as the markers would be ok provided that you allow the DSL the ability to **escape** the characters.  This is typical of operations on text which need parsing.

As an example check out the typical regular expression syntax which enables '/' as the seperator, whilst letting the user specify an escape character such as '\'. You may get some more ideas from the likes of such Unix tools as; **awk**, **sed** and **grep**

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to think a standardized format is the way to go, with [JSON](http://www.json.org/) being my personal choice because of it's simplicity. Not only does that help to avoid parsing issues since others have already though about it, you are also given a lot more tools to work with over the life of the project.